# TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] when trying to connect to bitcoin rpc from a pc on the same local area network

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, client

I have a laptop with win10 installed. It is now running a full bitcoin node perfectly. I am already able to make rpc requests from the laptop using python and get valid responses. The laptop is connected to the Internet using a LAN port on a Router that also has WiFi option. Now the question is: is that possible to make bitcoin rpc requests from another PC that is connected to the same router but through Wifi? When I try to do that I get a timeout error which I cannot recognize why. I tried to add a line to my `bitcoin.conf` to possibly increase the timeout parameter as `rpcclienttimeout=200` but it doesn't seem to work. The whole content of my configuration file is as following:

```
server=1
daemon=1
txindex=1
rpcuser=***
rpcpassword=******
rpcallowip=192.168.1.0/24
rpcclienttimeout=200
#rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
#rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
```

Am I missing something? PC#1's IP which is running the bitcoin node is `192.168.1.104` and PC#2's IP which is supposed to get rpc access is `192.168.1.102`.

When I run the following python code from PC#1 I get my supposed responses perfectly, But when I run the second python script from PC#2 I get timeout error.

The Code run from PC#1:

```
from time import time_ns as time
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from rpcreq import *
import json
import os

def avg(L):
    return sum(L, 0.0) / len(L)

rpcPort     = "8332"
rpcHost     = "127.0.0.1"
rpcUser     = "******"
rpcPassword = "******"

serverURL = ("http://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}").format(
        user=rpcUser,
        password=rpcPassword,
        host=rpcHost,
        port=rpcPort
    )

method = 'getblockcount'
params = []
resp   = rpcreq(method, params, serverURL)
nBlock = resp['result']
iters  = nBlock
iters  = 100
print(nBlock)

BlockHash = [0]*(iters)
method1   = 'getblockhash'


start = time()
for pj in range(0, iters):
    params          = [pj]
    resp            = rpcreq(method1, params, serverURL)  
    BlockHash[pj]  = [resp['result']]
    print(pj)

end = time()
endtns = (end-start)/(iters+1)
endts = endtns / 1000000000
print('Each Reading Will Take: ', endts, 'Seconds.')
print('Reading All Block Hashes Will Take: ', endts*nBlock/3600, 'hours.')

x      = np.arange(0.0, iters, 1)
y      = BlockHash

x = [*x]
List = [
            ['Height']            + x,
            ['BlockHash']         + y,
        ]

with open("BlockHashFirst{}.csv".format(iters), 'w', newline='') as rF:
    wr = csv.writer(rF, dialect='excel')
    for i in range(len(x)+1):
        wr.writerow([r[i] for r in List])
```

The Code run from PC#2:

```
from time import time_ns as time
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from rpcreq import *
import json
import os

def avg(L):
    return sum(L, 0.0) / len(L)

rpcPort     = "8332"
rpcHost     = "192.168.1.104"
rpcUser     = "******"
rpcPassword = "******"

serverURL = ("http://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}").format(
        user=rpcUser,
        password=rpcPassword,
        host=rpcHost,
        port=rpcPort
    )

method = 'getblockcount'
params = []
resp   = rpcreq(method, params, serverURL)
nBlock = resp['result']
iters  = nBlock
iters  = 100
print(nBlock)

BlockHash = [0]*(iters)
method1   = 'getblockhash'


start = time()
for pj in range(0, iters):
    params          = [pj]
    resp            = rpcreq(method1, params, serverURL)  
    BlockHash[pj]  = [resp['result']]
    print(pj)

end = time()
endtns = (end-start)/(iters+1)
endts = endtns / 1000000000
print('Each Reading Will Take: ', endts, 'Seconds.')
print('Reading All Block Hashes Will Take: ', endts*nBlock/3600, 'hours.')

x      = np.arange(0.0, iters, 1)
y      = BlockHash

x = [*x]
List = [
            ['Height']            + x,
            ['BlockHash']         + y,
        ]

with open("BlockHashFirst{}.csv".format(iters), 'w', newline='') as rF:
    wr = csv.writer(rF, dialect='excel')
    for i in range(len(x)+1):
        wr.writerow([r[i] for r in List])
```

The second code is only different on the parameter `rpcHost`.
When running the second code I get a full error as:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Any tips on where I am mistaking the concept?

Comment: `rpcbind` answer length too short